# Mean of multi level nested lists in python

Tags: python, list, average, nested-lists

I have a list like this

```
b= [
    [
        [[1],[2],[3]],
        [[4],[5],[6]],
        [[7],[8],[9]]
        ],
    [
        [[1],[2],[3]],
        [[4],[5],[6]],
        [[7],[8],[9]]
        ], 
    [
        [[1],[2],[3]],
        [[4],[5],[6]],
        [[7],[8],[9]]
        ]
]
```

this list can have up to 10 nested lists (here we only see 3).
I want to average this list in such a way that in the end, I have

```
b= [
        [[1],[2],[3]],
        [[4],[5],[6]],
        [[7],[8],[9]]
        ]
```

notice that the first element of the first nested list is average among all of the other nested elements. to be more precise all the ones should be average together. then all the 2s should be averaged together and this goes on until 9. and at the end, I have to preserve the structure as I showed above.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Raskayu I have tried a 3 nested level for loops which takes a lot of space and time. and I have tried with zip function but I noticed that zip works until 2 levels, not 3.

Comment: I can help lemme start replit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy` is your friend in cases like this. If we convert `b` into a `np.array` it has a shape of `(3, 3, 3, 1)`. The `1` here refers to the length of your inner lists. We can the use the `mean` method along the first axis to get your answer (you can convert this back to a list but you might want to stick with `numpy` if you are doing more analysis).

```py
import numpy as np

answer = np.array(b).mean(axis=0).tolist()
```

where `answer` is

```py
[
 [[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]],
 [[4.0], [5.0], [6.0]], 
 [[7.0], [8.0], [9.0]]
]
```

If you want to keep the answer as integers then you can explicitly request the array to be of `int` type:

```py
np.array(b).mean(axis=0).astype(int).tolist()
```